# utc time in kotlin multiplatform giving wrong value

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

How to get current utc time in kmm ? I tried below code but it gives time 01/01/1970 and it return 0 value.

```
DateTime.now().utc.milliseconds
```

Comment: Looks like you are using the Java `DateTime` class - https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#now-- You want to use the koltinx datetime library for multiplatform projects, allowing you to use its apis in common code, currently joda time won't resolve in common code.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [kotlinx-datetime](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime) then simply doing `Clock.System.now()` would provide time in UTC.

Not sure what `DateTime` object you're using in your question!

Comment: That is now deprecated, use `Clock.System.now()` instead.